# One LocationListener in whole application

Tags: android, gps, location, locationmanager, locationlistener

I need to implement one LocationListener in my entire application.

I know that I can use service with LocationListener, but the problem is that I have to use some notifier on location changed. It is not enough when I am able to get last location whenever I want, because I need current position in all Activities immediately when it changes.

So in pseudo code I need something like that:

`myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                notifyAllActivities(location);
            }
            };`

and in every Activity:

`void onNotify(Location location) { //... }`

Comment: Accept an answer that works for you so others may find it useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the service call sendBroadcast() to broadcast an Intent. Add the longitude/latitude as extras to that Intent. In each activity that needs the location, register a BroadcastReceiver for the intent and get the lng/lat from the Intent's extras in the receiver's onReceive()

Comment: So I will have to create my service intent in this service class, put some extras there and just sendBroadcast() from this service?
Then I need inner class which extends BroadcastReceriver and on every receive only change my location which I get in Intent argument?
Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Just declare a new BroadcastReceiver() in your activities, pick up the extras in its onReceive. Make sure you register it onResume() and unregister it in onPause().

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using [CommonsWare's LocationPoller library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll)?

It's known to be pretty robust and I have personally used it in one of my location-based applications.

One of the good things about it is it's compatibility with using `Service`; which is what you need to get location updates even when the app is in the background. It acquires a `WakeLock` to wake up the phone, get the location and then releases it gracefully.

Comment: I will check it, because I don't know this library yet.

Comment: It's easy to set up. There's a demo attached in it too. Good luck!